# How to do string concatenation in gdb/ada

Tags: gdb, ada

According to the manual, [string concatenation isn't implemented](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_14.html#SEC149) in gdb. I need it however, so is there a way to achieve this, perhaps using array functions?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you'd like to do, if it was implemented? Since I'm not familiar with this particular gdb feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a copy of gdb around to try this on, but perhaps this line from later in the Ada section of the document will help you?

> Rather than use catenation and
>   symbolic character names to introduce
>   special characters into strings, one
>   may instead use a special bracket
>   notation, which is also used to print
>   strings. A sequence of characters of
>   the form `["XX"]' within a string or
>   character literal denotes the (single)
>   character whose numeric encoding is XX
>   in hexadecimal. The sequence of
>   characters`["""]' also denotes a
>   single quotation mark in strings. For
>   example,      "One line.["0a"]Next
>   line.["0a"]"
>
> contains an ASCII newline character
>   (Ada.Characters.Latin_1.LF) after each
>   period.

Answer (score -1):

For Objective-C:

```
[@"asd" stringByAppendingString:@"zxc"]


[@"ID: " stringByAppendingString:(NSString*) [aTaskDict valueForKey:@"ID"]]
```